# JQuery JSONP Callback Error

Tags: jquery, json, callback, jsonp

I have a simple JQuery Stockwatcher app, which makes a JSONP request but the callback function is not getting called. I have the JSON call for this app working, but at somepoint it is going to be cross domain, hence I have to make is JSONP.

What am I doing wrong? When I run this code, the Error function gets called.

```
function loadData(data) {
    alert("Load Data");
    $.each(data.stocks,function(i,item){
        $("#results").append('Title:'+item.symbol+' ==  Price:'+item.price+'</p>');
    });
}   

$(document).ready(function(){
var url='http://localhost:8080/StockWatcherServer/stockwatcher/stockPrices?q=';
var query;
    $('button').click(function(){
        query=$("#query").val();
        // Assign handlers immediately after making the request,
        // and remember the jqxhr object for this request

        //$.ajaxSetup({ crossDomain: true, scriptCharset: "utf-8" , contentType: "jsonp; charset=utf-8"});
        $.ajax({
            url : url+query,
            type: "GET",
            dataType: "jsonp",
            jsonp : "callback",
            jsonpCallback: "loadData",
            success: function(data) {alert("Success");},
            error: function(data) { alert("Error"); },

            });        
       });
});
```

Here is my JSON Output, which I can see in Firebug

```
{"stocks": [
  {
    "symbol": "IPOD",
    "price": 20.2182603350167,
    "change": 0.3128265006354697
  }
]}
```

Thanks
Rajesh

Comment: is your server method prepared to handle jsonp?

Comment: The difference between json and jsonp is made by the server : it's the server which indicates the callback by answering `thecallback(thejson)` instead of just `thejson`. Maybe having a look at this JSONP server answer will make it more clear : http://canop.org:8001/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is JSON, not JSONP. If you are doing cross-domain JSON request, it must be JSONP not JSON. Different port is cross-domain.

This is the JSONP that your request should be returning based on your code. Additionally, your loadData method will be overridden by jquery IIRC.

```
loadData({"stocks": [
  {
    "symbol": "IPOD",
    "price": 20.2182603350167,
    "change": 0.3128265006354697
  }
]})
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked. I had another tomcat instance on a different port and I tested with that.